# have requirejs to run callback when the module is loaded

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, js-amd

I need to load css when my module is loaded, so I did it like this using shims :

```
function loadCss(url) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
}

requirejs.config({ paths: paths, shim: {
    'easyzoom': {
        'deps': ['jquery'],
        init: function () { loadCss('/lib/easyzoom/css/easyzoom.css'); }
    }}
});
```

It works for other libraries like Datatables because they are non-Amd modules. But for Amd modules, requireJs doesn't look for shims so will not raise my init function.

Is there any way to have a callback called after a module is loaded ? Or load an Amd module as it was a plain javascript file to have shims looked for ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining a `shim` for a proper AMD module (one that calls `define`) results in undefined behavior.

What you can do is use [`map`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) as follows:

```
map: {
    '*': {
        easyzoom: 'easyzoom-intercept'
    },
    'easyzoom-intercept': {
        easyzoom: 'easyzoom'
    }
}
```

What this does is specify that when any module (`'*'`) requires the module `easyzoom`, the module `easyzoom-intercept` should be loaded instead. However, when `easysoom-intercept` wants to load `easyzoom`, the module `easyzoom` should be loaded. You then create a `easyzoom-intercept` module like this:

```
define([easyzoom], function (ez) {
    loadCss('/lib/easyzoom/css/easyzoom.css');
    return ez;
});
```

This code will be executed as soon as `easyzoom` is loaded.

Comment: Thank you ! for loading css require-css is good but your answer is perfect for my question.